# ビルドパラメータを保存→OKが出たらビルド開始…という方法はありますか？

Tags: jenkins

Jenkinsにて、

1. オペレータが複数あるビルドパラメータを入力（この段階ではビルド開始できない）
2. マネージャがパラメータを確認し、OKを押す
3. オペレータ側に「ビルド」ボタン表示、実行
   ※2番でビルド開始されても可です。

上記の様なフローでビルド出来るといいなと思うジョブがあるのですが、
実現するためのプラグインはありますか？

2週間ほど探っているのですが、今のところ見当たりません。
どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

試したこと無いのですが workflow plugin で input で Proceed or Abort の入力ができるようです。
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
早速プラグインを入れてみましたので、確認してみます。
多機能そうなので、すぐに動作確認できるかは分かりかねますが試してみたいと思います。